# no text displayed in firefox 9 webpages

Tags: 11.04, firefox

11.04 64bit and there is a problem with Firefox.
Firefox doesn't display texts in websites for example in www.yahoo.com it doesn't show any text (for example there is mail Javabutton but it doesn't have text on it!) and when i click on Javabuttons nothing happen!! even it doesn't show news texts on this site.
and there is same problem in other sites.
i removed Firefox completely and install it again but it didn't fix.
please help me!

[image]

Comment: What version of firefox, what version of Ubuntu, and what firefox extensions or customizations do you have ? My guess would be a corrupt extension. Disable all your extensions and re-enable them one at a time. If the fails, try starting firefox with a fresh profile `firefox -P`

Comment: i am using ubuntu 11.04 and it is firefox 9.0. i tried what you said and it didn't fix.

Comment: Are you using a custom Unity theme ?

Comment: i put image of my browser.

Comment: Try changing back to the default theme (I wonder if it is theme related).

Comment: do you mean firefox theme or my ubuntu theme? my firefox theme is on default

Comment: both themes please

Comment: I did! there is no change!

Comment: There is a duplicate question with a solution in this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/118346/firefox-doesnt-display-website-text

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10. The problem was solved after I deleted my custom fonts.

I keep my fonts in "/user/share/fonts/truetype/**fonts from web**". When I copied my "old" fonts into this "fonts from web" folder, Firefox went blank. Took me about two days though to realise the problem. As soon as I deleted custom folder, Firefox is back. Some of the old font must have been coliding. Have to investigate more.