# Firefox doesn't display website text

Tags: 11.10, firefox, fonts, display, text

Firefox 11 doesn't show any text on some sites as Google and Youtube. 
Also Lotus Symphony doesn't show many UI Labels. This problem occurred suddenly.

> Firefox display error:
>   [image]

---

> Symphony display error: 
>   [image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a problem with your system's fonts. Try reinstalling the font. You can see a guide to this [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-TrueType-Fonts-on-Ubuntu).

You can also try this:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93828/no-text-displayed-in-firefox-9-webpages) seems very similar to yours (I would say is duplicated).

Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with your fonts. I had this problem on different machines.

To solve it I had to set the appropriate rights of the fonts and regenerate the font cache. You can use the following script to fix the display of fonts in Firefox.

Change `yourname` in the `MY_USER` variable to the appropriate username.

```
 #!/bin/bash
MY_USER="yourname"

# set rights of the font system folders
chmod -R 755 /usr/share/fonts
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share/fonts 
chmod -R 755 /etc/fonts

# Recreate font cache
fc-cache -rv


# Change user font cache
# set rights
chown -R "$MYUSER":"$MYUSER" "/home/$MYUSER/.fontconfig"
chmod -R 755 "/home/$MYUSER/.fontconfig"

# rebuild cache
su $MYUSER -lc "fc-cache -rv"
```

Comment: I had this same issue with Firefox 20.0 and Ubuntu 12.10 (dual-boot with Windows 7).  I had copied several MS fonts from the Windows partition to `/usr/share/fonts/` and run `sudo fc-cache -f -v`, only to have Firefox end up with completely blank pages.  Turned out that the fonts I'd copied in were set to `600` instead of `644` or `755`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look under the **Firefox Preferences** -> **Content** and see what **Default Font** is set there, like in the screenshot. 
[image]

Now see if you have that font installed in Ubuntu System. If not (which i think is **not** the case, since common applications in general use common fonts, that come with the installation) either install it afterwards, or use another font as default in Firefox.

Also you might want to take a look under the **Advanced-Button** -> **Default Character Encoding** and make adjustments there! To me it seems, that your Encoding is wrong which is the problem if not mistaken!

If that still does not resolve your problem, please edit your post and add a screenshot and/or more information about your settings that you use in FF.
[image]