# Website display issues in Firefox 57 Quantum

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, fonts, websites

After upgrading to Firefox 57 Quantum many website have rendering issues, such as empty frames, missing text or fonts, etc.
I use Kubuntu 16.04 64 bit. 
So far, I've tried:

- Restarting Firefox in safe mode
- Disabling "hardware acceleration"
- Wiping out my profile
- Purging Firefox and reinstalling
- Running Firefox from a clean user account

But nothing helped so far.

Any tips on how to solve this are much appreciated

Comment: Related post on SU: [Firefox 57 cannot display Arial on Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1269366/109256). Apparently a bug in Firefox 57 according to the comments found there.

Comment: Thanks, but that did help. However, the comments there led me to a blog post that answers this question.

Comment: I too am having the same issue since updating to Firefox 57. It seems there is already a thread regarding this font issue here: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/976985/firefox-websites-with-custom-fonts-not-displaying](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976985/firefox-websites-with-custom-fonts-not-displaying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this seems to be caused by a conflict with TexLive installation of fonts.

This [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976985/firefox-websites-with-custom-fonts-not-displaying) deals with it and offers the following solution:
In `about:config`, set

```
security.sandbox.content.read_path_whitelist
```

to

```
/usr/local/texlive/
```

And restart firefox

[This](http://alicious.com/firefox-57-font-missing/) blog post also discusses it and offers the following workaround:
Under Menu -> Fonts & Colors -> Advanced... -> Tick off "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above"