# Most fonts broken in firefox after update to 57 (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: firefox, fonts

After updating to Firefox "quantum" all text on most webpages is gone or show as small squares.

[image: image of the askubuntu.com homepage as see in Firefox quantum]

The issue occurs on most websites including google, askubuntu.com and the built in firefox new tab page. It does not occur on mozilla.org or a few other sites I've randomly tested.

Starting Firefox from terminal yields this error message:

```
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3897): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'Ubuntu 11'
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3897): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: file not found
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3897): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: file not found
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:3897): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-engine='PangoFcShapeEngine', font='Ubuntu 11', text='●'
```

### EDIT:

This appears to be caused by the combination of having fonts stored in a non-default location (on a separate drive from my OS) and [this sandbox security](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418240) bug in firefox 57.

Comment: Did you have custom fonts selected in your previous version of Firefox?

Comment: I have Ublock Origin add-on in FF and there is a "disable remote fonts" option in there. This can sometimes give the same impression, although, mostly FF will display with default fonts. 
Do you have the same ?

Comment: @Piloti I also use uBlock origin. I tried disabling it and it did not have any effect.

Comment: @pj-singh I don't have any custom fonts selects in my previous version of Firefox that I'm aware of.

Comment: This seems like it has the same underlying cause as [Firefox - Websites with custom fonts not displaying](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976985/firefox-websites-with-custom-fonts-not-displaying) however the accepted answer does not solve my issue. The file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` does not exist on my system and I have not installed `fonts-texgyre`. I also tried unsettling "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" which helped but many sites still don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [in the bug report on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418240#c7) this can be solved by:

1. typing `about:config` into the address bar
2. searching for security.sandbox.content.level
3. changing the value of from 3 to 2

Setting the value to 1 (as suggested https://askubuntu.com/a/977199/292055) also fixes the issue but is not necessary. According to [the discussion on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418240#c7) setting it to 2 simply "reduces the strength of the sandbox to the build 56 level."