# Firefox 57/57.04 does not display website text

Tags: upgrade, firefox, fonts

This is a variant of [Firefox - Websites with custom fonts not displaying](https://askubuntu.com/q/976985/446253): the problem is the same, but the solutions do not work for me. 
Moreover, I have found that two computers behave differently, even though settings touched upon in that post are the same. 
So the cause of the trouble must be elsewhere.

**The problem has been solved in Firefox 58.02**

### Situation

Both OS's are Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Both Firefoxes are 57 [*]. Both computers have texlive installed inside \opt. In both computers `less /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` gives

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<dir>/opt/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
<dir>/opt/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
<dir>/opt/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

#### Computer A

In FF57, in Edit > Preferences > Languages and appearance > Advanced, the situation is

[image]

In FF57 after typing `about:config` and heading for the fixes suggested in the post above, the result is
[image]

The upgrade from FF56 to FF57 went very well on this computer.
No issue with fonts.

#### Computer B

In this computer the FF upgrade has spoiled the visualization of the fonts. All the default FF settings are the same as in computer A. 
None of the tips of the post mentioned above work, such as editing the line `security.sandbox.content.write+path_whitelist`.
To see back the fonts, I need to untick the permission of displaying website fonts, which is a workaround.

### Aim

I would like to allow pages to choose their own fonts and pinpoint the reason why the font rendering of FF57 fails in Computer B.

### Question

Any tips and directions to understand what goes wrong with computer B?

### Note

[*] Same problem with 57.04

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but in Firefox, open the console (With the `F12` key). Make sure `CSS` is togged on then see if there are any relevant errors or warnings related to fonts. (click on the funnel icon next to the trash icon if the filters are not visible by default). https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxDH.png

Comment: @Dan There are indeed errors. Surely they appear regardless of whether the pages are allowed to set their own fonts on computer B. Verbatim:  `Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.
ccm.base.css:41:2
Unknown property ‘-moz-opacity’.  Declaration dropped.
ccm.base.css:42:2
Unknown property ‘zoom’.  Declaration dropped.
960_24_col.css:1:5556
Error in parsing value for ‘padding’.  Declaration dropped.
[website address removed]:31:54
Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped`. Still misty.